# How do I know which object is asking the delegate for information?

Tags: macos, cocoa, delegates, protocols

In my design, choosers tell an app controller how many items, and of which color, the user would like to see in each of two Views. I have a single NSView object description (myView.h, myView.m) which the controller instantiates twice. When the user adjusts a chooser to change, say, the number of items to be drawn in viewOne, the App Controller updates its local variable for this qty, and tells viewOne to redraw itself. As part of redrawing itself, viewOne needs to ask the delegate (App Controller) how many items to draw. When this happens via the protocol, **by what mechanism does the delegate know that it is viewOne who is asking for the qty variable?** i.e. how does the delegate know which variable to respond with?

[image: diagram of my intentions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can (not sure if I should) use isEqual: in the delegate's routine, to determine which object called:

```
- (int)numberOfItemsInTheView:(myView *)aView {
    int itemCount = 0;

    if([aView isEqual:[self viewOne]]) {
        itemCount = 5;
    } else if([aView isEqual:[self viewTwo]]) {
        itemCount = 18;
    }
    return itemCount;
}
```

It is the isEqual portion/statement that I was not aware of or understanding. Regarding Josh's answer, I can see that I may not fully understand the implications and/or requirements (conventions?) of the protocol/delegate coding structure.

Comment: In a case like this, it's OK to use direct pointer equality to test if it's the same object. So, `if (aView == [self viewOne]) ...`. You're actually interested in object identity, not equality. You want to know if it's the *same* object, not just one which is equivalent. Now, for classes which don't override the default semantics of `-isEqual:`, it use pointer equality to determine object equality, so they are the same. And any view class is very likely to use those default semantics of `-isEqual:`. So, the method you showed is fine; I'm just explaining further.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, pointer comparison isEqual: tells me that the address of aView (the object calling this routine) and the address of viewOne (a myView object that I know about) are the same. That's how I can determine which object is calling the routine. Do I have that correct?

Comment: The `-isEqual:` method is used to determine if two objects are equivalent, where "equivalent" is determined by the class of the object to which the `-isEqual:` message is sent. Comparing the two pointers like `if (aView == [self viewOne]) ...` determines if they are identical, the same exact object. Now, some classes define `-isEqual:` to also use pointer equality, so the two approaches produce the same result. Those classes define "equivalent" to mean "identical".

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to a delegate/data source call is, by convention, the object which is delegating, e.g.:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSApplication *)app;
- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
                rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row;
```

Inside these methods, `app` and `tableView` will be the requesters.

You should write your own delegate protocols to follow this pattern.

More in the ["Delegates and Data Sources" chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW3) of Apple's *Concepts in Objective-C*, although strictly this has nothing to do with the language itself: it's a pattern from the Cocoa (Touch) framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response. you wrote: "You should write your own delegate protocols to follow this pattern."   I think you are saying that I am not doing it (protocols and delegates) properly. Is that correct? If so, what is another convention that I can use to solve this problem? I mean, maybe instead of using a protocol, the App Controller sets the "number of items" variable in the myView object directly, for example? I understand that I am less than educated on this stuff (I am trying to learn on my own), please don't be afraid to use a bigger (more direct) stick in telling me where to look.

Comment: I don't know if you are or aren't. I wasn't even entirely sure if you were talking about your own protocol or one written by someone else. Either setting a property or using a delegate protocol could be a good choice: it depends other things in your design.