# HOW Implement Two Tableview with different delegate and datasource method In One Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, delegates, tableview

I Want to Implement Two Tableview In One Class.
I Khow objective-C does not support method overloading and also Khow How Use Two TableView With Same Method but what if have different parameter type?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView dismisWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(YALContextMenuTableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Comment: [How do I know which object is asking the delegate for information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33658398)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use two separate delegate method for two table views in same view controller.Instead of using two different table view delegate methods,you can better to set tag and name for table Views.

First table view name

```
 if([tableView isEqual:YourFirstTableViewName]) {
    ......//Your coding part
 }
 else if([tableView isEqual:YourSecondTableViewName]) {
    ......//Your coding part
 }
 else {
    ......//Your coding part
 }
```

Second use the tag for table view

```
if(tableView.tag == 0)  //Set tag whatever you want for first table view
{
     ......//Your coding part
}
else if(tableView.tag == 1)  //Set tag whatever you want for second table view
{
     ......//Your coding part
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm already use this for distinguish tableviews in delegate method but what i can do for parameters.two method have same name and different parameter return type:(UITableView *)tableView and (YALContextMenuTableView *)tableView

Comment: What does the result give you the solution?

Comment: i used second method because YALContextMenuTableView is subclass of UITableView.thank you.its work very well.

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate method, test for the type of table view class to determine which table view called the method,

```
if ([tableView isMemberOfClass:[YALContextMenuTableView class]]) {
   // do stuff for table 1
} else {
   // do stuff for table 2
}
```